# SQL Where for multiple condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement, report, where-clause

I am trying to filter a data in SQL 2008 using where to create purchase order report. I want to say if Item Price < $2 and we sold 1 sale at least within a month then show me all items their quantity on had are less than 12 AND if Item Price < $10 and we sold 1 sale at least within three months then show me all items their quantity on had are less than 4 AND if Item Price < $50 and we sold 1 sale at least within six months then show me all items their quantity on had are less than 2 AND if Item Price < $100 and we sold 1 sale at least within nine months then show me all items their quantity on had are less than 1
Is any way I can do that. Please advise with syntax. The price filed is PREC_1, Quantity filed is QTY_ON_HND, Sale Date is SALD_DAT and sold quantity is QTY_SOLD
I will appreciate your help

Here is the query I made

```
`SELECT
```

'-- Select from IM_IN'
`enter code here`M.ITEM_NO,
`enter code here`M.DESCR,
`enter code here`N.QTY_ON_HND,
`enter code here`CASE 
    `enter code here`WHEN N.QTY_ON_HND<0
    `enter code here`THEN 0
    `enter code here`ELSE N.QTY_ON_HND
    `enter code here`END AS QTY_HND,

`enter code here`N.LST_COST,
`enter code here`N.LST_RECV_DAT,

`enter code here`--Select from IM_ITEM
`enter code here`M.CATEG_COD,
`enter code here`M.ATTR_COD_1,
`enter code here`M.ITEM_VEND_NO,
`enter code here`M.ALT_1_UNIT,
`enter code here`M.ALT_1_NUMER,
`enter code here`M.PRC_1,
`enter code here`M.LST_COST,

`enter code here`--Select from PS_TKT_HIST_LIN

`enter code here`sum (S.QTY_SOLD) AS QTY_SOLD,
`enter code here`count (S.BUS_DAT) AS SALS_DATS

`enter code here`FROM
`enter code here`dbo.IM_INV N
`enter code here`INNER JOIN dbo.IM_ITEM M
`enter code here`ON
`enter code here`N.ITEM_NO = M.ITEM_NO

`enter code here`INNER JOIN 
`enter code here`dbo.PS_TKT_HIST_LIN S
`enter code here`ON
`enter code here`N.ITEM_NO  = S.ITEM_NO

`enter code here`WHERE S.BUS_DAT>getdate()-270 AND N.QTY_ON_HND <4 AND M.PRC_1 <2

`enter code here`Group by
`enter code here`M.ITEM_NO,
`enter code here`M.DESCR,
`enter code here`M.ITEM_VEND_NO,
`enter code here`M.CATEG_COD,
`enter code here`M.ATTR_COD_1,
`enter code here`N.QTY_ON_HND,
`enter code here`N.LST_COST,
`enter code here`N.LST_RECV_DAT,
`enter code here`N.LST_SAL_DAT,
`enter code here`M.ALT_1_UNIT,
`enter code here`M.ALT_1_NUMER,
`enter code here`M.PRC_1,
`enter code here`M.LST_COST,

`enter code here`Order by M.ITEM_NO`

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? Or are you asking someone to build the query for you?

Comment: *data in SQL 2008*  - I think you are not using MySQL, but SQL Server 2008

Comment: Here is the query I have created

Comment: Hi Neil B, I have added the code I have created to my message. I could not add it to the comment. I want to say Where CASE PREC_1 <2 AND N.QTY_ON_HND <12 and  S.BUS_DAT>getdate()-270 ELSE PREC_1 <10 AND N.QTY_ON_HND <4 AND  S.BUS_DAT>getdate()-180 AND PREC_1 <50 AND N.QTY_ON_HND <2 and  S.BUS_DAT>getdate()-90

Comment: Hi Madhur I have use SQL SERVER 2008 R2

Comment: And what is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need to combine 2 types of filtering.

"Item Price < $2" -> This needs a WHERE Clause

EG

```
WHERE [item price] < 2
```

" we sold 1 sale at least within a month"

This is an Aggregate type filter so you need to use HAVING

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Plus a Grouping clause

```
GROUP BY DATEPART(mm, bus_dt)
```

As you have a lot of criteria - I'd suggest you break it down and start at the top. Then work your way down once you have the first set of filters working ...

It might be beneficial to try and tabulate all the different criteria into a simple EXCEL table.

EG

Add a row for every OR and a column for every AND condition.

Bon Chance!

Comment: Thank you EG. Could you explain more how to do this?